# How to get client's IP in JAX RPC web services without Servlet Filter?

Tags: java, web-services, ip, soap-client, jax-rpc

I have to log the client's IP address who is using my JAX RPC web service server.

IBM adviced to use servlet filters and get the IP using HTTP Request:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21304368

Is there a different way to get the request?
I m using IBM WAS 8.5 and SOAP 1.2 for the server side.
Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :)

```
import com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.MessageContext;
import com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HTTPConstants;
```

.....

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) MessageContext.getCurrentThreadsContext().getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);

String clientIpAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");

if (clientIpAddress == null) {
    clientIpAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
}

System.out.println(clientIpAddress);
```